# Inserting the file name as column value in a csv file in R

Tags: r

I have a file called “Day1.csv” with X number or rows. I would like to create a new column that includes the file name (“Day1”) in each row (from 1 to X). I have seen similar posts but I cannot get it to work. I was wondering is someone could give me a hand with this. 
Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example of what you have tried so far.

Comment: Please put some data and some code that you have tried before and the error u get. Then we can try to help u.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
fn <- "Day1"
df <- read.csv(file=paste(fn, ".csv", sep=""))
df$filename <- fn
```

This way you can reproducibly fetch other filenames if you need (Day2, Day3, etc)

Comment: or `paste0(fn, ".csv")`

Comment: Thank you Luke. I have many files to go through so I was wondering if the name of the file can be automatically extracted so I dont have to type it each time.

Comment: You're welcome. Using `Sys.glob("*.csv")` will yield a list of all the .csv files in your directory.

Comment: Ive just found an easy way of extracting the file name `csvname<- basename(DataPathway)`